# Check if excel file has an xml file counter part with the same modified date

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Is there a way to check if there is an xml file in a directory that has the same modified date with an excel file.

Example.

```
ls
---
Apr 11 20:18 sample_excel.xls

Apr 11 20:18 sample1.xml
Apr 12 01:13 sample2.xml
Apr 13 14:01 sample2.xml
```

How to identify that sample1.xml has the same modified date with sample_excel.xls?

Edit: Apologies if my question wasn't clear. Ultimately. Goal is to check if there is an xml file in a folder that has the same modified date with an excel file.

I'm thinking to go with approach similar as below.

```
file1=sample_excel.xls
for xml_file in *.xml; do
        if [ $file1 -nt xml_file]; then 
        echo $xml_file
        else
        echo $xml_file
        fi
done
```

my problem the above code checks if file1 is newer than xml_file. what I want to check if it is of the same modified date.

Comment: Can you provide a full line instead of just Apr 11 20:18

Comment: Can you show what you've tried please?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but I'd guess `cut -f-3 -d' '|sort|uniq -d` will give you the list of duplicated dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you file only contain line like `Apr 11 20:18` you can use the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   if grep "$line" sample_excel.xls; then
      echo "Date $line found in file : sample_excel.xls"
   fi 
done < sample1.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

# returns the last modifiled date
function mdate() {
    local stat=$(stat "$1" -c %y)
    set -- $stat
    echo "$1"
}

xls="sample_excel.xls"
mdate_xls=$(mdate "$xls")

for file in *xml; do
    mdate_xml=$(mdate "$file")
    if [[ "$mdate_xls" = "$mdate_xml" ]]; then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

If you wish to compare the modification times with a minute accuracy, try instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

# returns the last modifiled time from the epoch
function mtime() {
    echo $(stat "$1" -c %Y)
}

# returns abs of difference
function absdiff() {
    local diff=$(($1 - $2))
    if [[ $diff -lt 0 ]]; then
        diff=$((-$diff))
    fi
    echo $diff
}

xls="sample_excel.xls"
mtime_xls=$(mtime "$xls")
TOL=60              # tolerance

for file in *xml; do
    mtime_xml=$(mtime "$file")
    if [[ $(absdiff $mtime_xml $mtime_xls) -lt $TOL ]]; then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: this might work mdate only returns up to date. how to return including time and mins? `ls -ltr -> -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 Mar 14 12:14 test.txt`  `mdate test.txt -> 2018-03-14`

Comment: woud it be correct to use %Y instead? this would return epoch

Comment: The result of `stat` without splitting with `set` holds hour and min.  But why you need hour and min?  I thought you want.to compare the files just with last modified date.

Comment: Or do you want to include hour and min as well as date in the comparison?

Comment: yes sir. i want to include hour and min as well in the comparison.

Comment: Understood.  I am now out of office and will update my script in 40 minutes. Hold on please.

Comment: I've updated the script to compare with a minute accuracy. My assumption is that the modification times of the two files may not have the exact same timestamp due to the processing timing. Then it will be safer to calculate the difference of the timestamps of the files and check if the difference is less than some tolerance, say 60 seconds.  If my assumption and/or suggestion do not meet your expectation, please let me know.